react-native-google-mobile-ads gives error on expo ios build
When I try to import react-native-google-mobile-ads, Expo gives multiple errors in my iOS build.
Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNGoogleMobileAdsModule' could not be found
Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered.
I reconfigured my ios build and tried to change a few things in the ios folder but I kept getting the same error

First of all, I removed the react-native-google-mobile-ads component from app.config.js file from expo component and changed it as follows:
'react-native-google-mobile-ads': {
ios_app_id: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyyyy',
android_app_id: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyyyy',
},

Then I added the following to the Info.plist file in the ios folder:
<key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
<string>ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyyyyyy</string>

Then I added the following to the AppDelegate.m file, also in the ios folder:
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h>

Finally, I ran the following in the terminal:
cd ios
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf Podfile.lock
pod install
cd..
expo run:ios


I faced the same error, and managed to resolve the issue by following the below steps:
1. Adjust app.json

Before the "react-native-google-mobile-ads" was at the root level.
Now the "react-native-google-mobile-ads" should be moved at root > expo > extra
more details here

EXAMPLE
// old app.json
{
  "expo": {
  // ...
  },
  "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
    "android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx",
    "ios_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx"
  }
}

// new app.json
{
  "expo": {
    // ...
    "extra": {
      "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
        "android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx",
        "ios_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx"
      }
    }
  }
}

2. Update react-native-google-mobile-ads library
The issue is resolved by version 14, "react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^14.0.0", which can be found here
Edit
Currently, both structures are required for a fully functional application that uses "react-native-google-mobile-ads". Issues have been open about this change and can be found here
EXAMPLE
// functional app.json
{
  "expo": {
  // ...
    "extra": {
      "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
        "android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx",
        "ios_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx"
      }
    }
  },
  "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
    "android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx",
    "ios_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx"
  }
}

